# Multiple transformation of coordinates of a smartphone's orientation sensor

Tags: c#, android-orientation, device-orientation

[Regarding Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION :](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

As I understand it, each value represents an angle between a vector from the coordinate center to the North Pole(or some other strong magnet) and the respective axis.

Let's say, the smartphone is fixed on a sphere's surface. The sphere is rotating around it's center. It has the radius r.

How do you estimate the angle the smartphone would have in the sphere's center between a fixed coordinate system's axes in the sphere's center and the respective imaginary (=projected) axes?

How do you do it in c#?